# Hasura graphQl update trigger repeats many time

Tags: graphql, hasura

My table columns look like `name`, `email`, `phone`, and `pin`.

I'm using Hasura for collecting user details.

Problem:

I want to hash the `pin` field using some hashing algorithm. So I decided to have a separate AWS Lambda function to convert a plain `pin` to hashed one and `update` it to the same column.

[image]

Now I set a trigger (when `pin` get updated it will trigger the webhook). I successfully updated the hashed one to my database. But the problem is after lambda updated the field Hasura re-trigger the webhook again. The process is to keep on going until I shut down my Hasura instance.

In Hasura documentation they mentioned below

> In case of UPDATE, the events are delivered only if new data is
> distinct from old data. The composite type comparison is used to
> compare the old and new rows. If rows contain columns, which cannot be
> compared using <> operator, then internal binary representation of
> rows by Postgres is compared.

however, after the lambda update, the data is same as old one but why it is kept on calling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `action` for this instead of `trigger`. With that way, database only store hashed pin.